# I am building voice recorder in which i m getting issue when i am using Audio Demo library in ios 6. Can anyone help in clearing my issue?

Tags: iphone, ios7, avaudiorecorder

My issue are-

```
"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController-C29511237FC0C9C8.o
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController-932D04AFE18818B5.o
  "_AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate-DFB03E57E4A805B5.o
  "_AVFormatIDKey", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController-C29511237FC0C9C8.o
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController-932D04AFE18818B5.o
  "_AVNumberOfChannelsKey", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController-C29511237FC0C9C8.o
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController-932D04AFE18818B5.o
  "_AVSampleRateKey", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController-C29511237FC0C9C8.o
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController-932D04AFE18818B5.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController-C29511237FC0C9C8.o
      objc-class-ref in ViewController-932D04AFE18818B5.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioRecorder", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController-C29511237FC0C9C8.o
      objc-class-ref in ViewController-932D04AFE18818B5.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController-C29511237FC0C9C8.o
      objc-class-ref in ViewController-932D04AFE18818B5.o
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate-DFB03E57E4A805B5.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
```

Comment: Could you please mention more on the issue...when this error occurs.That would be helpful to answer your question clearly

Comment: Check your Frameworks are atteched?

Comment: sorry friends i wrote ios 6 but actually i am using ios 7.

Comment: shadow@ when i run my app error is given.

Comment: viruss mca@ can u plzz elaborate which framework and how to connect those framework.

Comment: seems not linked to AVFoundation.framework. Check your project settings.

Answer (score 2):

```
AVFoundation.framework
```

is likely the one you need.

if you still get an error, try adding

```
AudioToolbox.framework
```

as well.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbled upon this while trying to `import AVFAudio`, it can be resolved by also importing `AVFoundation`:

```swift
import AVFoundation
import AVFAudio
```